# Understanding Symmetric tensor field

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I am reading an article in which author calls some basic tensor analysis result.

He states in general we define on $\mathbb R^N$ that
$$ \mathcal T^k(\mathbb R^N):=\{\xi:\,\mathbb R^N\times\cdots\times\mathbb R^N (k \operatorname{times}) \to \mathbb R,\,\xi\,\,k\operatorname{-linear}\} \tag 1$$ and  $$ \operatorname{Sym}^k(\mathbb R^N):=\{\xi:\,\mathbb R^N\times\cdots\times\mathbb R^N (k \operatorname{times}) \to \mathbb R,\,\xi\,\,k\text{-linear and symmetric} \} \tag 2$$ be the vector space of $k$-tensors and symmetric $k$-tensors, and $\xi$ is called symmetric if $$\xi(a_1,\ldots,a_k)=\xi(a_{\pi(1)},\ldots,a_{\pi(k)})\tag 3$$ for all permutation group $\pi$ of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$.

For simplification, let's assume $N=2$. Then it says that for $k=1$, $\text{Sym}^1(\mathbb R^2)=\mathbb R^2$ and $\text{Sym}^2(\mathbb R^2)=S^{2\times 2}$ i.e., the space of symmetric matrices.

I got confused here. Let's take $k=2$. It looks to me the elements $\xi$ in definition $(2)$ is a function, a map right? $\xi$ should map from $\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. So, how could it be a matrix?

Moreover, let's suppose for $k=2$,
$$
\xi=
\begin{bmatrix}
\xi_{11} & \xi_{12}\\
\xi_{21} & \xi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then what is $\xi(1)$ and $\xi(2)$? Since from the definition of $\text{Sym}^2(\mathbb R^2)$ I should have $\xi(1,2)=\xi(2,1)$...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does $\xi(1)$ mean? $\xi$ needs to be fed a pair of vectors in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I confused too. But this is what $(3)$ means right? I am just trying to make sense of $(3)$.

Comment: No, your notation makes no sense. (3) tells you that $\xi(v,w)=\xi(w,v)$. The basic example you should keep in mind for $k=2$ is dot product (inner product) of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bilinear mapping $M : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ using the standard inner product and your matrix $\xi$ above:
$$M(x, y) = \langle y, \xi x \rangle$$
Likewise, each bilinear mapping defines a matrix using that relationship.

Comment: I see. But still, what is $\xi(1)$ and $\xi(2)$ in this case?

Comment: @Deonoising  I didn't see where they were defined above, so I can't tell.  Perhaps, the first and second column of the matrix $\xi$.  Since $\xi$ has two arguments they aren't directly well defined.

Comment: ok.. But how I understand that $\text{Sym}^2(\mathbb R^2)=S^{2\times2}$?

Comment: @Denoising - The mapping above defines a bijection between symmetric bilinear mappings and symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices.  I wouldn't necessarily say they are equal, but they are isomorphic as vector spaces.