# The explicit expression of symmetric tensors, and the Symmetrize gradient of symmetric tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377988/understanding-symmetric-tensor-field) long time ago but I am still confused...

Let me repeat some definitions. In general we define on $\mathbb R^2$ that
$$ \mathcal T^k(\mathbb R^2):=\{\xi:\,\mathbb R^2\times\cdots\times\mathbb R^2 (k \operatorname{times}) \to \mathbb R,\,\xi\,\,k\operatorname{-linear}\} \tag 1$$ 
and
$$ \operatorname{Sym}^k(\mathbb R^2):=\{\xi:\,\mathbb R^2\times\cdots\times\mathbb R^2 (k \operatorname{times}) \to \mathbb R,\,\xi\,\,k\text{-linear and symmetric} \} \tag 2$$ 
be the vector space of $k$-tensors and symmetric $k$-tensors, and $\xi$ is called symmetric if $$\xi(a_1,\ldots,a_k)=\xi(a_{\pi(1)},\ldots,a_{\pi(k)})\tag 3$$ for all permutation group $\pi$ of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$.

Now take $k=2$. For a function 
$$
w = 
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{11} & w_{12}\\
w_{21} & w_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that $w\in C^{\infty}(\operatorname{Sym}^2(\mathbb R^2))$, we have $w_{12}=w_{21}$. Then my question is, what is $\mathcal E(w)$? could you write it explicit for me in term of $w_{ij}$? where $\mathcal E$ is the Symmetrized gradient defined by
$$
\mathcal E(u) = \frac12(\nabla u+\nabla u^T)
$$

Also, if $w\in C^{\infty}(\operatorname{Sym}^k(\mathbb R^2))$, what is $w$ actually? If I write $w=\{w_{i^1i^2.\ldots i^k}\}$, which of them should equal? and what is $\mathcal E(w)$?

Those question troubles me for a long time. Please help!

Comment: What kind of object is $u$ here? A smooth $1$-form on $\Bbb R^2$, presumably?

Comment: being $w$ symmetric... wouldn't be ${\cal E}(w)=w$?

Comment: @Travis The definition I have in hand is $u$ is a vector function so $\nabla u$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix

Comment: @janmarqz $\mathcal E$ is a differential operator so at least I expect some $\partial w$ in $\mathcal E(w)$?

Comment: oh yes, error ... my fault

Comment: Is $\Bbb R^2$ is endowed with the standard metric? As $u$ is a vector field, $\nabla u$ is a $(1, 1)$-tensor, so it only makes sense to talk about symmetrizing it after lowering (or raising) an index, which requires a metric.

Comment: @Travis In paper it says we use the norm $|\xi| = \sqrt{\xi\cdot \xi}$

Comment: @Travis So in my understanding, yes, $\mathbb R^2$ is endowed wit the standard metric

Comment: Okay, that norm arises from the standard inner product, so without more context I'll assume so. In that case $\nabla_{\partial_{x^j}} (u_1 \partial_{x^1} + u_2 \partial_{x^2} = (\partial_{x^j} u_1) \partial_{x^1} +  (\partial_{x^j} u_2) \partial_{x^2}$. This allows you to extract the components of $\nabla u$ with respect to the standard basis, after which you can symmetrize them.